# How do you test different subject lines when you are using path optimizer

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have an email and want to test 3 different subject lines and 3 different preheaders.

We have applied AMP script in the email to record the Subject Line and Preheader (eg. SL1, PR1, SL2, PR2, SL3, PR3).

I've applied path optimizer in journey builder. With a 30-30-30 split with one of the subject line options in each.

The winner will be automatically selected.

When test send the emails, I only recieve the one that is put in the email builder content. Not the tailored ones in the journey builder.

Can I assume when the emails go out, the subject linse will be modified per what was edited in journey builder.

Appreciate the help